# MediaQuery.of() is keep showing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add 2 buttons to my flutter project while watching a video tutorial I am new to flutter

```
void main() {
  runApp(MainScreen());
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

This is the only lines i coded and I'm getting this error

```
MediaQuery.of() called with a context that does not contain a MediaQuery.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `MaterialApp` to wrap all widgets. Try this:

```
  
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Main Screen'),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

You can read more from [this blog](https://medium.com/codespace69/flutter-error-mediaquery-of-called-with-a-context-that-does-not-contain-a-mediaquery-3a1d50e5c9cf).

Comment: This works thanks but I still don't understand how the YouTube guy doesn't get this error anyway thanks again